# Dagger 2 - Injecting interface in implementation class - "Attempt to invoke interface method on a null object reference"

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am always getting null pointer exception when I try to inject interface in implementation class. here is my code:

Getting:

> Nullpointer error in **LoginManagerImpl** class at line:
>   @Override
>   public String getLoginResponse(String request) {
>     return networkManager.getLoginResponse(request);
>   }

here **networkManager is always null**, can you please look into the code.

Below is my source code:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    @Inject
    NetworkManager networkManager;

    @Inject
    LoginManager loginManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getApplicationComponent().inject(this);

        loginManager.getLoginResponse("valid Login Request");
    }
}

public interface NetworkManager
{
    String getLoginResponse(String request);
    String getUserDetailResponse(String request);
    String getABCResponse(String request);
}

public interface LoginManager
{
    String getLoginResponse(String request);
}

public class LoginManagerImpl implements LoginManager {
    @Inject
    NetworkManager networkManager;

    public LoginManagerImpl(Context context)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public String getLoginResponse(String request) {
        return networkManager.getLoginResponse(request);
    }
}

public class NetworkManagerImpl implements NetworkManager {

    public NetworkManagerImpl(Context context)
    {

    }
    @Override
    public String getLoginResponse(String request) {
        return "valid login response fetched from server";
    }

    @Override
    public String getUserDetailResponse(String request) {
        return "valid user deails";
    }

    @Override
    public String getABCResponse(String request) {
        return "valid ABC request response";
    }
}

@Module
public class AppModule {

    DaggerApplication application;

    public AppModule(DaggerApplication application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    DaggerApplication provideDaggerApplication() {
        return application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Context provideApplicationContext()
    {
        return application.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public LoginManager providesLoginManager(Context context)
    {
        return new LoginManagerImpl();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public LoyaltyCardManager providesLoyaltyCardManager(Context context)
    {
        return new LoyaltyCardManagerImpl(context);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public NetworkManager providesNetworkManager(Context context)
    {
        return new NetworkManagerImpl(context);
    }
}

@Singleton
@Component(
        modules = {
                com.dagger.component.AppModule.class
        })
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    void inject (LoginActivity activity);

    NetworkManager getNetworkManager();
    LoginManager getLoginManager();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

There are two ways for you to let Dagger inject dependencies like the `networkManager` field into `LoginManagerImpl`.

1. Annotate its constructor with `@Inject` and change `providesLoginManager(Context)` to

   ```
   @Provides @Singleton
   LoginManager providesLoginManager(LoginManagerImpl manager) {
     return manager;
   }
   ```

   That will mean Dagger will provide the `LoginManagerImpl`, and your `@Provides` method binds `LoginManager` to that.
2. If you want to instantiate `LoginManagerImpl` yourself in `providesLoginManager(Context)`, then also request a `MembersInjector<LoginManagerImpl>` and use it to inject fields like `networkManager`:

   ```
   @Provides @Singleton
   LoginManager providesLoginManager(Context context, MembersInjector<LoginManagerImpl> membersInjector) {
     LoginManagerImpl manager = new LoginManagerImpl(context);
     membersInjector.injectMembers(manager);
     return manager;
   }
   ```

For your example, I'd recommend option #1. Using `MembersInjector` is really useful for classes that you cannot let Dagger instantiate, like Android Activities.

Answer (score 4):

Field injection is not automatic. You need to provide those dependencies through the constructor, or you need to invoke member injection on the class via the component.

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {    
    @Inject
    NetworkManager networkManager;

    @Inject
    LoginManager loginManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getApplicationComponent().inject(this);

        loginManager.getLoginResponse("valid Login Request");
    }
}

public interface NetworkManager {
    String getLoginResponse(String request);
    String getUserDetailResponse(String request);
    String getABCResponse(String request);
}

public interface LoginManager {
    String getLoginResponse(String request);
}

@Singleton
public class LoginManagerImpl implements LoginManager {
    private final NetworkManager networkManager;

    @Inject
    public LoginManagerImpl(NetworkManager networkManager) {    
        this.networkManager = networkManager;
    }

    @Override
    public String getLoginResponse(String request) {
        return networkManager.getLoginResponse(request);
    }
}

@Singleton
public class NetworkManagerImpl implements NetworkManager {
    @Inject
    NetworkManagerImpl(){
    }

    @Override
    public String getLoginResponse(String request) {
        return "valid login response fetched from server";
    }

    @Override
    public String getUserDetailResponse(String request) {
        return "valid user deails";
    }

    @Override
    public String getABCResponse(String request) {
        return "valid ABC request response";
    }
}

@Module
public class AppModule {
    DaggerApplication application;

    public AppModule(DaggerApplication application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Provides
    DaggerApplication provideDaggerApplication() {
        return application;
    }

    @Provides
    Context provideApplicationContext() {
        return application.getApplicationContext();
    }
}

@Module
public abstract class ManagerModule {    
    @Binds
    abstract LoginManager loginManager(LoginManagerImpl impl);

    @Binds
    abstract LoyaltyCardManager loyaltyCardManager(LoyaltyCardManagerImpl impl);

    @Binds
    abstract NetworkManager networkManager(NetworkManagerImpl impl); 
}

@Singleton
@Component(
        modules = {
                com.acme.di.component.AppModule.class,
                com.acme.di.component.ManagerModule.class
        })
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    void inject (LoginActivity activity);

    NetworkManager getNetworkManager();
    LoginManager getLoginManager();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to resolve the error by adding *`android:name="my_application_class_name"`* to the application tag in AndroidManifest file.

Comment: Oh! Really, it helped me. Why you downvote it? I upvoted! Android Studio shows uncorrect error in this case